# Angular :- components of different modules getting loaded

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

new bee to angular concepts, in practice I have 2 modules,

1) events module which is main module (it has app.module.ts && routes.ts)

2) user module it has its own user.module.ts but routes defined for this module(in user.routes.ts) come from main routes.ts for eg.

```
{ path: 'user', loadChildren: 'app/user/user.module#UserModule' }
```

this is defined in routes.ts

what I know is if I hit any link from some module only components related to that particular module will get loaded,

But what I can see in my application is that,

1) it is taking a bit time to load a page even though it just a small app

2) when I look into developer tool i.e. F12 on browser, on hitting of 'user/profile'   which belongs to user module, components of events modules also getting loaded.

Why is that it suppose to load all the components of user module only right?

Answer (score 0):

you can create 2 routing files

```
export const Routes1: Routes1[] = [
 {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: HomeComponent
 },
 {
    path: '/test',
    name: 'test',
    component: TestComponent
 }
];
```

and call in in your app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { Routes1 } from './routeModule1';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
})
@RouteConfig(RouteDefinitions)
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: Hi Fateh, thanks for your reply, I'm new learner of angular and I have not come across the concept of @RouteConfig yet , I just wanted the explanation about what I'm trying to do and what I'm thinking about the same is correct or not. I will try your solution for sure but my question is  I have stated it as loadChildren is the reason for loading the components of other module